# how to open snippingtool clip mode

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a desktop application (C#, Windows 10) than when the user press a button it automatically execute snipping tool on Clip Mode [capture the image].... and save the selected piece[image] in a picturebox.... it works fine on Win10.... but not on Win11

This is the error:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
> at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)

```
private void btnImagen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string _Path;
    if (!Environment.Is64BitProcess)
        _Path = "C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\SnippingTool.exe";
    else
        _Path = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\SnippingTool.exe";

    pbxImagen.BackgroundImage = null;
    if (Process(\_Path, "/clip") == true)
    {
        pbxImagen.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
        pbxImagen.BackgroundImage = Clipboard.GetImage();
    }
}

public virtual bool Process(string \_Dir, string Arg)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process \_Process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    _Process.StartInfo.FileName = \_Dir;
    _Process.StartInfo.Arguments = Arg;

    _Process.Start();
    _Process.WaitForExit();
    return (_Process.ExitCode == 0) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: please use tags actually relevant to your question and just things you are using eg. the tag visual studio is similar irrelevant as if you tagged your question with mouse or keyboard because you use those devices to click

Comment: try this `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "SnippingTool.exe")`

Comment: Type "where snippingtool.exe" at the command prompt to discover it is no longer stored in c:\windows.  Probably best to rely on the PATH environment variable, so `_Path = "SnippingTool.exe";`